# JavaScript usage testing showing issues with iPhone and iPads

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad

I have run a test on my site to try to see the volumes of users with and without JavaScript running and it has thrown up some odd results. I want the site to work for users without JavaScript, but am trying to justify how much effort should be given to this.

This test was done by having a block like this at the top of the BODY tag:

```
<img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="" width="1" height="1" />
<img id="imageTest2" src="" alt="" width="1" height="1" />
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("imageTest2").src = "/images/javascript.jpg";</script>
<noscript><img src="/images/noscript.jpg" alt="" width="1" height="1" /></noscript>
```

I then inspected the Apache logs to gather these stats:

- 97.5% of users saw the normal image tag and the JavaScript image
- < 0.01% of users saw the normal image tag and the NoScript image
- 2.45% of users saw the normal image tag, but didn't see the JavaScript or NoScript images

The 2.45% is the odditiy. Digging further, over 85% of these are from iPads and iPhones running iOS7.

I found an article on the UK Gov site who ran a similar test who gave the following options as reasons why there are differences (https://gds.blog.gov.uk/2013/10/21/how-many-people-are-missing-out-on-javascript-enhancement/)

- corporate or local blocking or stripping of JavaScript elements
- existing JavaScript errors in the browser (ie from browser add-ons,
  toolbars etc)
- page being left between requesting the base image and the script/noscript image
- browsers that pre-load pages they incorrectly predict you will visit
- network errors, especially on mobile devices

Most of these don't sound like they would account for over 2% of the users apart from the pre-loading feature, however I have tested this on Safari (the 'Preload Top Hit' feature) and found that it requests the HTML and executes the JavaScript on iPads and iPhones, so this is not causing the issue.

Google Analytics (which runs using JavaScript) shows that 43% of the website users are using iPhone or iPads, so this is not affecting all iPhone/iPad users.

Does anyone have any ideas why Safari users on iPhones and iPads are not always executing JavaScript?